# Can background jobs complete if you exit a browser after submitting a request?

Tags: google-chrome, background, delayed-job, resque

I'm new to using background jobs (and much of programming in general) - so I'm aware this must be an simple question, but I haven't found an answer in my research.

I've written a Ruby on Rails web app that I have deployed to Heroku. After a form is submitted, it runs a background process for a web scraper script that takes about 10 minutes to complete.

My question is: If I quit my browser after the request is submitted,, will the background job still run and complete? If it will not, will just closing the window still allow it to complete?

My hunch is that it will, since the request goes through the server, but I just want to make sure. Thanks for your input!

Comment: This is actually a pretty interesting question.  Try it and see what happens--that's what I'm going to have to do :)

Comment: That's an excellent idea - I'll go ahead and do that now :)

Answer (score 0):

I think so, Chrome now stays open, but I'm not sure if the webpage does.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ben Brammer's suggestion, I just went ahead and tried it myself! (It's amazing how I failed to think of something so obvious.)

Yes, it works fine: I quit Chrome immediately after submitting the form to begin the script. I then checked, and the script went through with no issues whatsoever.